# egrep lines starting with r and ending with g

Tags: regex, shell, unix, grep

I need to find and display lines in the shell using egrep that start with r and end with g.

I have

```
egrep -e "^r*g$" testfile.txt
```

but it is not giving me any results, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Although you can place a `$` at the end of a double quoted string, it would be much better to write that with single quotes: `'^r.*g$'`

Comment: You're confusing regular expressions with the file matching patterns ("globbing") used by the shell. In a regexp, `.` matches a single character, and `.*` matches zero or more characters; in a file matching pattern, it's `?` and `*`, and `.` is not special. File matching patterns are less powerful, but tend to be more convenient for their limited purpose of selecting files.

Answer (score 14):

adding a `.` should work

```
egrep -e "^r.*g$"
```

It basically means : everything that starts with a r, then is followed by zero or more anything, and then ends with g.

tested against

```
r fsgdfs gfsdg
fooo bar
rfoo g
fdsqfdsq

rg
```

it returns

```
r fsgdfs gfsdg
rfoo g
rg
```

Answer (score 1):

The `*` is matching on the `r`, not "anything inbetween". Update it to `.*` and you should see results:

```
egrep -e "^r.*g$" testfile.txt
```